# Find the largest area of a rectangle inside a circular segment of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$.

Tags: geometry

> What is the largest area of a rectangle inside a circular segment of $\frac{2\pi}{3}$ and radius $r$? 
>   One side of the rectangle lies on the circle's chord. 
>   We want a geometrical solution (as opposed to analytic geometry or trigonometry).

If $r$ is the radius, then the rectangle has an "elevation" of $\frac{r}{2}$ above the $x$ axis.
If $A$ is the upper right vertex of the rectangle and $O$ the center of the circle, also $\theta$ the angle of $OA (= r)$ with the $x$ axis, then the area is 
$$ 2r\cos θ (r\sin θ-\frac{r}{2}) $$
I can't think of any purely geometrical solution. 
[image]

Comment: It all comes down to whether maximising height or width has the greatest impact.

Comment: @StubbornAtom: Actually the maximum width is $r \sqrt{3}$ and maximum height is $r/2$. None of the two result to maximum area.

Comment: Can you provide a diagram? It is not clear what is the "$x$-axis" here.

Comment: It is unclear what is meant by a "geometrical solution". May we use that $1+1=2$?

Comment: Am I seeing this wrong? Isn't that an arc of $2\pi/3$?

Comment: Apologies, yes, I made an edit! I just saw the missing "2"!!

Comment: So, we are looking for the maximum area of ABCD as C moves between F and H.

Comment: What prompted you to believe that a purely geometric solution is within our grasp?

Answer (score 3):

I just wanted to say to the optimistic geometer out there that this is the value of the maximum area when $r=1$, as per Wolfram Alpha:

$$
2 \\ \times \\
\left(1-\frac{2}{\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{2\left(9-\sqrt{33}\right)}-\sqrt{33}\right)\right)^2+1}\right)
\\ \times \\
\left(\frac{2\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{2\left(9-\sqrt{33}\right)}-\sqrt{33}\right)\right)}{\left(\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\left(\sqrt{2\left(9-\sqrt{33}\right)}-\sqrt{33}\right)\right)^2+1}+\frac{1}{2}\right)$$

What does this tell us? To start, it *doesn't* tell us that a purely geometric solution is impossible. $_{_\text{However, we do learn that $+100$ rep isn't worth the challenge.}}$

Comment: Wolfram Alpha sometimes (usually?) generates unnecessarily-complicated expressions. A cleaner version of the above is $$\frac{1}{16} \sqrt{6 (69 - 11 \sqrt{33})} = 0.3690\ldots$$ (BTW: This calculation agrees with Narasimham's value of $\sin\theta = \frac18(\sqrt{33}+1)$.)

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Still cheating -
using the quadratic equation for $\sin\theta$,

\begin{align} 
\sin^2\theta-\tfrac14\sin\theta-\tfrac12&=0
\tag{1}\label{1}
,
\end{align}
but the roots are found from its coefficients 
by the old geometric method as follows.

1. Point $H$ is $r$ units to the right of the center $O$.
2. Point $U$ is $r/4$ units above the $H$.
3. Point $V$ is $r/2$ units to the right of $U$.
4. Point $W$ is the center of the circle, $|OW|=|WV|$
5. Intersections of that circle with the vertical line $UH$
   gives two points, $X_+$ and $X_-$,
   whose $y$-coordinates are the roots of \eqref{1} scaled by $r$,
   and the $y$-coordinate of the point $X_+$ 
   is the sought coordinate $A_y$.

Comment: On what software you did you make this nice sketch construction? Geogebra?

Comment: @Narasimham: Nope. [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

What makes you assume that a geometric construction is possible at all?

Anyways trying to find maximizing area by differentiation of

$$ \frac{A}{r^2} = \cos \theta\cdot ( 2 \sin \theta -1) $$

which results in maximum rectangle area solution

$$  \sin \theta=\frac{\sqrt{33}+1} {8}   $$

A geometric re-construction by such prior knowledge already sounds like cheating.

The power of the big circle drawn is $33$

A geometric construction sketch is nevertheless given. Circle diameters are not drawn to proportion on purpose because narrow lines would not show detail ... the right angle $ TQP$ does not even look right angled at $P$. A Geogebra sketch can be made though.

Required $\theta$ is $\angle TQP$ of green/red triangle.

[image]